# Многоязычность в CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysql

Здравствуйте. Я первый раз хочу сделать многоязычность на сайте (Codeigniter). Не очень хорошо знаю принцип. Вот таблица такая (пример)

```
Articles  -> id,en_title,ru_title
```

по-моему так должно быть. Там на сайте должен быть линк для языка. Ну не знаю. Пожалуйста, напишите один controllew, model, view. Заранее огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ну уже давно все написано: [CodeIgniter Internationalization Views](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Category:Internationalization::Internationalization_Views_i18n/)

Comment: а как там поставить линк чтобы выбрать язык?